# "not all code paths return a value" compile error in a String method having DateTime params

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following method, it is not returning value.

```
private string ValidateExpirationDate(DateTime dtEffectiveDate,DateTime dtExpirationDate)
{
    if (dtExpirationDate <= dtEffectiveDate)
        return "Expiration Date: Must not be before Effective Date";
}
```

Compiling this code gives the following error:

> Error: not all code paths returns a value.

Comment: What do you want to return if `dtExpirationDate > dtEffectiveDate` ?

Comment: read the error message. Not all paths through your code return a value. You can google for the message too

Comment: If you read the actual words in the error message, it should be very clear what the problem is and how to fix it. The **words** in the message are there for a reason - they contain **information**.

Answer (score 1):

you need to return a value even if the "if" condition is not executed. example:

```
private string ValidateExpirationDate(DateTime dtEffectiveDate,DateTime dtExpirationDate)
{
  if (dtExpirationDate <= dtEffectiveDate)
     return "Expiration Date: Must not be before Effective Date";

  return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what others have already posted (just my personal preference from a readability standpoint)

```
 private string ValidateExpirationDate(DateTime dtEffectiveDate,DateTime dtExpirationDate)
 {
     if (dtExpirationDate <= dtEffectiveDate)
         return "Expiration Date: Must not be before Effective Date";
     else
         return string.Empty; //or some other value you'd want if the first check fails
 }
```

Comment: Thnx to all, its my mistake.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning value when if() is executed. When your if condition is false function will return nothing.